# QGIS- Output bmp files are tilted

Tags: qgis, raster, utm, rasterization

I am new to QGIS. My goal has been to convert a .shp file to a raster, eventually to a .bmp for an input map into a separate piece of software I am using... this separate software also needs the map to be in UTM.
My steps after inputting vector layer:

1. Change CRS from Conus Albus to WGS 84 / UTM.
2. Use Rasterize... Conversion- Vector to Raster (using Byte as the output data type)
3. Raster...Conversion- Translate (Convert Format)- Save to File- BMP

When I open this .bmp from my desktop (viewing in XnView or Windows Photos) the .bmp is severely tilted to the right...

I must be missing something simple? Any advice?[image]
[image]

Second photo is the output.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS uses **gdal_rasterize** command to convert vector to raster. It cannot reproject between spatial reference systems (SRS). So your first step has no effect. Your third step uses **gdal_translate** to change output format which cannot reproject to target SRS, too. Your steps should be:

1. Vector to raster conversion of the layer (it keeps the source SRS) into GeoTiff memory layer
2. Export/Save as your memory layer into a GeoTiff file, change the target SRS too.
3. Raster/Conversion/Translate save into a BMP file (it also keeps SRS)

Finally you get two files a BMP and an aux.xml (for georeference). If you need a world file georeference (e.g. bpw or wld) for your target software add creation option WORLDFILE=YES:

[image]

If you reproject your data it is natural to have rotation if the orientation of the two SRS are not the same. Check your BMP in QGIS!